# Line breaks in TikZ nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

I have this code that outputs a small family tree

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      man/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20},
      woman/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=red!20,rounded corners=.8ex},
      grandchild/.style={grow=down,xshift=1em,anchor=west,
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
      first/.style={level distance=6ex},
      second/.style={level distance=12ex},
      third/.style={level distance=18ex},
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=5em}]
        % Parents
        \coordinate
          child[grow=left] {node[man,anchor=east]{Jim}}
          child[grow=right] {node[woman,anchor=west]{Jane}}
          child[grow=down,level distance=0ex]
        [edge from parent fork down]
        % Children and grandchildren
        child{node[man] {Alfred}}
        child{node[woman] {Berta}}
        child {node[man] {Charles}}
        child {node[woman]{Doris}};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

and what I want to do, is to write 2 lines of text in each box (e.g. Jim and underneath his DOB). How do I break a line in order to do that? `\\` doesn't work.

Here is a printscreen of the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use a table (two rows) (tabular env) in the content; though, I have no the required package to check if it would work or that is not allowed. E.g.

```
  \begin{tabular}{c}
     Jim \\
     DOB \\
  \end{tabular}
```

If `\\` does not work since it was changed someway by the package, then you could try `\cr`, but I suppose it could not work and if it works, it is bad LaTeX (too much TeXish).

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine. Yes it is kind of a bummer but it works!

Answer (score 39):

Add `align=center` to the style if you want to use `\\`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  man/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20, align=center},
  woman/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=red!20,rounded corners=.8ex, align=center},
  grandchild/.style={grow=down,xshift=1em,anchor=west,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
  first/.style={level distance=6ex},
  second/.style={level distance=12ex},
  third/.style={level distance=18ex},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=5em}]
    % Parents
    \coordinate
      child[grow=left] {node[man,anchor=east]{Jim}}
      child[grow=right] {node[woman,anchor=west]{Jane}}
      child[grow=down,level distance=0ex]
    [edge from parent fork down]
    % Children and grandchildren
    child{node[man] {Alfred \\ 05-04-83}}
    child{node[woman] {Berta \\ 05-04-99}}
    child {node[man] {Charles \\ 05-04-77}}
    child {node[woman]{Doris \\ 05-04-80}};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DanielNovais: You may apply `align=center` to all nodes via `every node/.style={align=center}`.